# How to create LyX inset without text-box (input box)?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm working on a custom layout file for LyX, I'd like to create a custom inset without the text/input box. I've seen other commands from the insert menu without it, such as "Page Break", but I haven't found where these are defined (attempted a grep search but came up empty).

At the moment this is what the code looks like:

```
InsetLayout MyInset
      LyxType       Custom
      LabelString   "My Inset"
      LatexType     Command
      LatexName     myLatexCommand
      Preamble
        \newcommand{\myLatexCommand}{
          Some output from command \\
        }
      EndPreamble
End
```

This produces the following in LyX:

[image: Result of layout style in LyX]

And in the compiled document:

[image: Result of layout in compiled document]

If I can't remove the input box, can I put a pre-filled text informing that it is not to be used and suppress its output in the compiled document?

Also is there any good exhaustive documentation/list of available style commands for LyX layouts? I've attempted to find any API-style list for creating layouts in LyX but come up short.

Comment: I believe there is complete documentation in Help > Customization under the section "The layout file format". Also note that looking at the layouts that LyX ships (in the lib/layout directory) is very helpful.