# How to create a keyboard-shortcut to custom insert at LyX?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Look at this question: [How to create LyX inset without text-box (input box)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396042/how-to-create-lyx-inset-without-text-box-input-box)
I want to create a keyboard-shortcut for one of my custom insert, it is possible?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Try the technique in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: @scottkosty, I don't understand how, can you give me an example please?

Comment: I tried to write out those steps as clearly as possible and with screenshots. Which step do you get stuck on?